# Automate Logarithmic Regression in Datorama Dashboard with SFTP/FTPS/Email?

Tags: sftp, datorama

I want to run logarithmic regression in Datorama, but it looks like the only way to do this is to send a report through SFTP/Email/FTPS/AzureBlob etc. to R Studio, then send the results back to Datorama via Datastream configurations.

Has anyone done this? How do you send from DTR to R? Would love some guidance.

Thanks!